# Is there any way to prevent a textarea placeholder from crossing over as a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, placeholder

I've created a new page to simplify a process at work, but to facilitate the user-friendliness and low barrier of entry, I'm trying to keep what I'm doing confined to a **single html file**. However, the approach I'm going for requires that I create a javascript pop-up using a portion of the page itself that I've blocked out using

```
<div id="head"></div>
```

and

```
<div id="body"></div>
```

This portion contains a form, and everything works fine, except that the pop-up translates the placeholder string into the value by placing it between the  tags.

This is my Pop-Up script:

```
function openwindow(url){
  var newHead = $("#head").html();
  var newBody = $("#body").html();
  NewWindow=window.open( url,'PopUp','resizable=no');
  NewWindow.document.write(newHead+newBody);
  NewWindow.focus(); };
```

And this is a portion of newbody (#body) variable

```
      <input id="cause" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Description">
      <br><br>
      <textarea id="desc" type="text" placeholder="Supplemental"></textarea>
```

..But this is what I get in the pop-up:

```
      <input class="input" id="cause" type="text" placeholder="Description">
      <br><br>
      <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Supplemental" type="text">Supplemental</textarea>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an IE browser problem, check:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811408

I checked Chrome, Firefox and Opera and works fine. Only IE.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that the #head and #body refer to

    <div id="head"></div>

and

    <div id="body"></div>

tags that block off the code used for the popup. I've edited the original post to reflect this.

Comment: Everyone in the office uses IE, unfortunately. Wow! that's a great find though. I'm glad to know it's not just my coding. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an odd workaround, but I hope someone can come up with something better. I added a line of jQuery code that executes onLoad that replaces the entire line with what I'm want. Not the greatest, but it's serviceable I suppose.

```
$('#replace').html('<textarea id="desc" type="text" placeholder="Supplemental"></textarea>');
```